Using gRPC in Unreal Engine 4
I'm using Unreal Engine 4.26. While my game is running, I want it to communicate with a gRPC server to perform certain actions.
Is there a plugin available that allows me to easily implement a gRPC client using blueprints?
Thanks for your assistance!
I searched on Google for some solutions, but I didn't found something helpful. Some plug-ins are very expensive or aren't compatible with UE4.26. And I didn't found a solution with only using blueprint.

Infraworld is a solution that enables Unreal Engine 4 to work with Google gRPC services using either C++ or Blueprints.
https://github.com/vizor-games/InfraworldRuntime

TurboLink is an unreal engine plugin that enables Google gRPC to work with Unreal Engine using C++ or Blueprint. It is compatible with UE 4.27 and 5.
https://github.com/thejinchao/turbolink
